# LINQ C#, sum column of same field

Tags: c#, linq

In this list there are results by a query. Might be that there are fields with same field ID_articolo (same product id).

```
var list = dbContext.Set<Bolle_dettaglio>()
    .Where(r => r.ID_bolla == id && r.ID_articolo != 0);
```

Here is how it can be at the moment:
Example:

```
id_articolo   Quantity
  1         | 2   <
  2         | 1
  3         | 2
  1         | 3   <
```

The final output I want is:

```
id_articolo   Quantity
  1         | 5        <- sum
  2         | 1
  3         | 2
```

It has to sum the quantity of the same id_articolo, which function does that?

```
var test = list.GroupBy(u => u.ID_articolo).ToList();
```

Tested this groupby but it isn't working as i mean to be.

Answer (score 2):

try this with group by and sum:

```
dbContext.Set<Bolle_dettaglio>().GroupBy(r => r.id_articolo)
.Select(
    g => new
    {
        id_articolo = g.Key,
        Quantity = g.Sum(s => s.Quantity), 
    });
```

Comment: 'ID_articolo' and no accessible extension method 'ID_articolo' accepting a first argument of type 'IGrouping<int?, Bolle_dettaglio>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 

it gives error in Key = g.ID_articolo

Comment: I fixed it. You need to use the group key.

Answer (score 1):

> *"Tested this groupby but it isn't working as i mean to be"*

It's not clear how you tested your results, nor how it *"isn't working"*, but when you do this:

```
var test = list.GroupBy(u => u.ID_articolo).ToList();
```

...you now have a list of groups of objects, where each group contains objects that share the same `Key` (which is the `ID_articolo` property). The groups themselves are similar to a `List<Bolle_dettaglio>`, and you can treat it as such with `System.Linq` extension methods, including getting the `Sum` of the `Quantity` property.

For example, in a Console Application you could output the results from your code like:

```
// Write a header
Console.WriteLine("Id\tQuantity");

// Output the id for each group, along with the sum of it's quantity
test.ForEach(grp => Console.WriteLine($"{grp.Key}\t{grp.Sum(item => item.Quantity)}"));
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: https://gyazo.com/5145e1b91f5c824edfff149748d8d3d3
I got how sum quantity, but not how keep the other attributes:
Look at the result: https://gyazo.com/8745a4d9c82d7192efb6efdc18ef394d
List also got other important attributes which i want to keep in the List (not anonymous list as it is now): as description, product code

Comment: If you want to keep the objects, then don't select an anonymous type. Use your original code and get the sums as above. If the code above is not what you are looking for, please let me know what requirement is not being met.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `GroupBy` your list accoring to id_articolo and then calculate the sum of `Quantity` field.

Something like:

```
var NewList=    dbContext.Set<Bolle_dettaglio>().GroupBy(x => x.id_articolo).Select(y => new 
                {
                    id_articolo = y.Key,
                    Quantity = y.Sum(z => z.Quantity)
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: The name 'ID_Articolo' does not exist in the current context.

it gives this as error in id_articolo = Id_articolo

Comment: @staff614 It's edited

Answer (score -1):

```
        var NewList = list.GroupBy(x => x.ID_articolo).Select(y => new
        {                
            id_articolo = y.Key,                
            Quantity = y.Sum(z => z.Quantita_)
        }).ToList();
```

this one works, but it has only two fields: id_articolo and quantity. This table has a lot of data and I need to keep them too, how can I make that with the groupBy

Comment: Your original code works fine, and keeps all the other properties with the objects returned. See my answer for how to get the `Sum` of `Quantity` from it.

Comment: Also, since this isn't an answer, you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59900428/edit) your original question with this additional clarifying information rather than posting it as an answer.